# Problems with a widget in Android

Tags: android, widget, android-pendingintent

At the moment, my android widget runs a PendingIntent when you click it. The problem is that if the activity is already running in the background, the widget runs it a second time. Is there any way to make the widget open the currently running version as opposed to a completely new one?

Comment: have you tried using the flags specified here - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mark your Activity as having a launchMode of singleTop or singleTask which should let you use the `onNewIntent` callback to receive the intent. See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode for more detail.